# Deleting files in Internal Storage folder android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and i am coding through internal storage in android.

I have written files to it using the code below

```
File mydir = getDir("users", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
        if (!mydir.exists()) {
            mydir.mkdirs();
        }

        //Getting a file within the dir.
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile" + i);
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The folder got created under

Now i want to delete the "users" folder with all its contents except one file. Say i want to delete entire content, except file named "File 56".
The code i used to delete entire users folder is,

```
public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
                deleteRecursive(child);
            }
        }

        fileOrDirectory.delete();


    }
```

Now how can i delete all contents except that particular file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply did it as,

```
public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
                if (child.getName().equals("myfile40")) {

                    System.out.println("File 40 - Not deleted");
                } else {
                    deleteRecursive(child);
                }
        }

        fileOrDirectory.delete();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something quick like this?

```
public void deleteRecursiveExcept(File fileOrDirectory, ArrayList<String> ignoreNames) {
    if(ignoreNames.contains(fileOrDirectory.getName()) return;

    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
            deleteRecursive(child);
        }
    }
    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like:

```
public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory, String fileNameToBeSkipped) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
            if (fileNameToBeSkipped == null || !child.getName().equals(fileNameToBeSkipped)) {
                deleteRecursive(child);
            }
        }
    }

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}

public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    deleteRecursive(fileOrDirectory, null);
}
```

And start deletion with:

```
deleteRecursive(getDir("users", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "File 56");
```